# Does UFW reset iptables on reboot?

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I connected to my remote Linux server to adjust my network settings, but I accidentally changed some rules using `iptables` instead of my preferred method, `ufw`.

I added the rules in `ufw` and then ran `iptables -F` to flush the rules from `iptables`. However, I forgot that this would block my SSH connections.

I would like to connect to my server again via SSH, but even though the port I am using for SSH is allowed on `ufw`, my flush of `iptables` is blocking me from connecting.

If I ask the server maintainer to manually reboot the server (i.e., disconnect and reconnect the power cord), will `ufw` reconfigure `iptables` to allow SSH connections (as configured in the `ufw` rules), or do I need to log into the server via a local TTY and reenter the rules into `ufw` to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ufw` doesn't need to flush `iptables` rules on reboot.  That happens automatically...or, more precisely, there are no iptables rules on a freshly booted Linux system until something sets them.

`ufw` does exactly that.  It will set the `iptables` rules to exactly what its configuration files tell it to set them as.   That's why programs like `ufw` exist - iptables rules are not persistent across reboots, so programs like `ufw` exist to provide persistence for firewall rules.

Comment: BTW, I'd recommend telling your server maintainer to plug in a keyboard and press Ctrl-Alt-Del rather than just power-cycle the server.   The chance of filesystem corruption is fairly low, but far from non-existent.

Comment: The server does not have a screen attached to it, so I don't think that the keyboard idea will work. On another note, doesn't Ctrl+Alt+Del only work on Windows machines?

Finally, if I'm willing to take the chance of filesystem corruption (which is lower than normal in my case because the server doesn't have a lot of read/write activity going on), all I would need to do to reset the `iptables` to the UFW rules is unplug the server and plug it back in?

Comment: yes, just reboot it. that's what i said in my answer.   btw: 1. screens and keyboards are independent of each other, you don't need a screen for a keyboard to work.  2. linux can trap keypress combinations and sequences, and most linux machines are configured to run `shutdown -r now` or similar on Ctrl-Alt-Del.  3. it's your server, you can reboot it however you want...but if you want to avoid the risk of fs corruption, then make it do a clean shutdown. I was just pointing out that the risk is low but not zero.   I often take that risk, but only after trying a clean shutdown fails.